# Why is epimorphism not defined as follows?

Tags: category-theory, definition, epimorphisms

Epimorphism in category theory, can be seen as a generalization of "surjective function" in **Set**.

But we could also have characterized surjective functions in **Set** as follows:

> **Definition (*)**. $f:A\to B$ is surjective if for all $Z$, and all $g:Z\to B$, there is a $g_f:Z\to A$ such that $g=f\circ g_f$.

In **Set** this definition characterized surjective functions, just as the standard definition for epimorphisms does. But in general categories, this definition is independent from the epimorphism definition (neither implies the other).

**Why choose the standard epimorphism definition over (*), or over some other definition that matches in Set, as a generalization of surjective function?** What makes the epimorphism definition desirable?

**EDIT**: Similarly for monomorphism: We can characterize injective functions in **Set** as:

> **Definition (&)**. $f:A\to B$ is injective, if for all $Z$ and all $g:A\to Z$, there is a $g_f:B\to Z$ such that $g=g_f\circ f$.

Comment: It's completely categorical?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, my definitions are categorical as well?

Comment: The existence of $g_f$ for every $f:Z\to B$ is equivalent to existence of a section $g:B\to A$.

Comment: @JulianRosen, your type signatures are different from mine so I'm not sure what you're saying.

Comment: @LeeMosher, my definition is not set-theoretic though........... My definition is purely categorical, and is a generalization of surjective functions JUST like the definition of epimorphism is a categorical generalization of surjective functions.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mean to say that the existence of $g_f$ for every $g:Z\to B$ is equivalent to the existence of $g_f$ in the single case $g=\mathrm{Id}_B$ (with $Z=B$).

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150851/motivation-behind-the-definition-of-monomorphism-and-epimorphism-in-category-the and more recently : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140841/morphisms-that-permit-arbitrary-lifts-extensions

Comment: Your Definition(*) characterizes surjectivity in the category of sets only because of the axiom of choice. (In fact, this characterization is equivalent to the axiom of choice.) Also, your proposed definition would give unexpected results in some other categories where the usual definition of epimorphism works fine. For example, in the category of groups (and also in the category of abelian groups), the unique homomorphism from a cyclic group of order 4 onto one of order two would not be an epimorphism.

Answer (score 8):

You definition corresponds to the concept of [split epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+epimorphism), which is stronger of that epimorphism.

However, when the category has a projective generator, then epimorphisms can be characterized with a similar concept to being surjective:

> In a category with a projective generator $Z$, a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is an epimorphisms if and only if for all $y:Z\to Y$ there exists $x:Z\to X$ such that $y=xf$ (morphisms composition in diagramatic order).

Recall that an object $Z$ is a generator if for each pair of distinct parallel 
morphisms $f,g:X\to Y$ there exists a morphisms $x:Z\to X$ such that $xf\neq xg$.
An object $Z$ is projective if and only if for each epimorphism $e:X\to Y$ and each morphism $y:Z\to Y$ there exists a morphism $x:Z\to X$ such that $y=xe$.

This condition is fullfilled, for example:

- in the category of sets by taking $\{\varnothing\}$ as projective generator;
- in the cateogry of modules over a ring taking the ring itself as projective generator;
- in the category of groups taking $\Bbb Z$ as projective generator.

The *only if* part follows since $Z$ is projective.
For the *if* part follows arguing by contradiction: if $f$ is not an epimorphism, then there exists a pair of distinct parallel arrows $u,v:Y\to W$ such that $fu=fv$.

[image]

Since $Z$ is a generator, there exists $y:Z\to Y$ such that $yu\neq yv$.
Let $x:Z\to X$ such that $xf=y$.
Then
$$yu=xfu=xfv=yv$$
a contradiction.

In that case, epimorphisms are also pullback-stable (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3105139)).

Comment: You might want to clarify for the OP and other readers that you write compositions in diagrammatic order.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Fixed, thank'you

Comment: It's worth mentioning that split epimorphism is a *much* stronger concept than epimorphism. Split epimorphisms are absolute, meaning they are preserved by *all* functors. Also, the existence of a splitting for all surjective functions in $\mathbf{Set}$ is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice. Indeed, "all epimorphisms split" is usually used as the categorical formulation of the Axiom of Choice. There are [many other kinds of epimorphisms](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/epimorphism#Variations) between (plain) epimorphisms and split epimorphisms.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at concrete categories, like groups and topological spaces for instance. In those categories, you can define a notion of surjectivity (resp. injectivity) by using the one from set, because you have a notion of underlying set-map.

Surely, any generalization of surjectivity (resp. injectivity) you have should be satisfied by those maps as well.

However, there are (tons, actually) some maps that have surjective (resp. injective) underlying set-maps, but that do not satisfy your condition: there are epimorphisms (monomorphisms) that are not split (your definition is that of a split epimorphism/monomorphism). Therefore, even if your condition is an interesting one, it can't be used to generalize surjectivity (resp.injectivity)